# Eclipse Oxygen's Project Structure Validator

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse Oxygen, I clicked `Preferences` and then `Validation`. I located `Project Structure Validator` and clicked Settings (the `...` button). I changed `Broken single-root rule` to `Ignore` (used to be `Warning`) and clicked `OK` and then `Apply and Close`.

But my warnings didn't disappear. So I went back and (unexpectedly) found that `Broken single-root rule` was still set to `Warning`.

I've tried all kind of combinations of `OK` and `Apply` buttons and Eclipse restarts, but the settings doesn't change. Any ideas on how I change the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work-around: First change to `Error` (and click `OK` and `Apply and Close`). Then go back and change to `Ignore`. This time the change will stick.